# How my class giving result without even returning from any function

Tags: javascript

Here I have written some JavaScript code with a class of functions.

How am I getting a result without returning from a function?

My code:

```
class myArray{
    constructor(){
        this.length = 0;
        this.data = {}
    }

    get(index){
        console.log(1)
        // return this.data[index]
    }

    push(item){
        this.data[this.length] = item
        this.length++;
        // return this.length
    }

    pop(){
        const lastItem = this.data[this.length - 1];
        delete this.data[this.length - 1];
        this.length--;
        // return lastItem
    }

    delete(index){
        const item = this.data[index];
        this.shiftItems(index)
        // return item
    }

    shiftItems(index){
        for (let i = index; i < this.length - 1; i++){
            this.data[i] = this.data[i + 1]
        }
        delete this.data[this.length-1]
        this.length--;
    }
}


const newArray = new myArray();
newArray.push('hey');
newArray.push('you');
newArray.push('!');
newArray.pop();
newArray.delete(1)
newArray.push('are');
newArray.push('nice');
console.log(newArray)
```

My output:

```
myArray { length: 3, data: { '0': 'hey', '1': 'are', '2': 'nice' } }
```

I am not able to understand from where the result is coming in JSON format.

Comment: Why are you expecting that you need to return from the methods? All the methods alter `newArray`, then you print the altered `newArray` at `console.log(newArray)`.

Comment: You're calling methods that modify the internal state of the object. Then you're printing the object. There is no need to return anything.

Comment: You are printing out the object `newArray` (using its built-in `toString` method). To print the contents of the `data` property you would need to do `console.log(newArray.data)`